# How to standardize time-series data when looking for extremes

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, biostatistics, confounding

I have time series data for several groups of animals (birds, mammals, reptiles etc) which shows speciation rates over time.

I want to see the effect of mass extinction events on these rates but I would like to make the various time series comparable (linear model of number of species ~ duration of extinction event). I want to do this because inherently some groups have higher speciation rates than others.

Is it appropriate to standardise each time series by taking the baseline speciation rate for each one before the extinction event? i.e. linear model of number of species ~ duration of extinction event + baseline rate.

Comment: Can you tell us some more about the data? Where from? how long time series? regularly spaced? how is measurement done? If data is nmber of speciation events in some time period, together with number of species in group as denominator, then maybe some form of poisson regression or related model? Standardization should **not** be done in that case!